# How to reset my password?

Tags: support, login

I received this mail to get my password back, but there is no link to reset the password.

> Someone requested an account recovery on Stack Overflow for mail@yahoo.com. If you did not request this, just ignore this email. We'll keep your account safe.
>
> You can log in to Stack Overflow using the following credentials:
>
> ```
> Facebook (mail@yahoo.com)
> Yahoo (mail@yahoo.com)
> ```

How can I reset my password?

Comment: Do you have a Stack Exchange Open Id?  Or do you use your yahoo and/or facebook credientials?  From the sound of what you are describing, you generally only log in via Yahoo and/or Facebook, so Stack Exchange has no control over the password (they won't even know what the password is)

Answer (score 7):

The email is saying that your Stack Overflow account is linked to your Facebook and Yahoo accounts.

Therefore, on the "Login" page, choose either "Facebook" (and login with your Facebook account), or "More login options", then click the "Yahoo" icon (and login with your Yahoo account).

If you've forgotten the passwords for *those* accounts, then you obviously need to reset *those* passwords on the respective site.

Comment: This does not answer my question? How do I reset/recover my password? There is no link in the mail to do that. ( I want to recover my password for the yahoo account).

Comment: @ClaudiuHaidu How does this sentence `If you've forgotten the passwords for those accounts, then you obviously need to reset those passwords on the respective site.` not answer your question?

Comment: So, I want to recover the password for my stack exchange account using the mail@yahoo.com address (which is also the username). I clicked the forgot password, received the mail and when I click on the yahoo account, it sends me to the same page. I would have expected a new password/repeat password screen.

Comment: @ClaudiuHaidu please educate yourself about how OpenID works. You have no specific password for your SO account, you login in with your yahoo credentials. If you forgot your yahoo password, you obviously need to use the yahoo.com password reset mechanism.

Comment: Claudiu: Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login, click "More login options", click the "Yahoo!" icon. Wait for the Yahoo login page to load. Enter your Yahoo email address, then enter your Yahoo password. Click login. Done.

Comment: ... if you've forgotten your Yahoo password, go to stackoverflow.com/users/login, click "More login options", click the "Yahoo!" icon. Wait for the Yahoo login page to load. Click "I can't access my account", fill in the details, and you'll be emailed a link from Yahoo to reset your Yahoo password. Once your Yahoo! password has been reset, you'll be able to login to Stack Overflow using the steps in my previous comment.

Comment: @ClaudiuHaidu: Glad it helped :).

Comment: I would be happy if Claudiu mark this as answer :)